# How to install Spotify Gnome?

Tags: gnome, spotify, media-buttons

I want to have media key support in Spotify, and searching around saw a program called "Spotify Gnome" [recommended](https://askubuntu.com/a/190822/37700).  But, when I go to [the site linked to](http://www.noswap.com/projects/spotify-gnome/), I can't figure out where to go to download a .deb, only how to get the source.  Is the only way to compile it myself?!  What repository do I have to add?

Can anyone give me a quick rundown on how to install Spotify Gnome?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the author of the software, I don't actually use Ubuntu myself, so I don't provide any packages.  However, it's just a simple Python script, so it doesn't need to be compiled at all.

You can either download the script itself directly from Github and copy it to /usr/local/bin (make sure to run `chmod 755` on the file first), or you can use Git to check out the source code repository and follow the installation instructions in the readme.  I strongly suggest the second method, as it will allow you to do a simple `git pull` in the repository in the future to update your copy of the script and install it again.

Comment: Quick question - how can I do the second method (I know, pretty basic, but I haven't used git before)?  What should I put into the terminal exactly?  Updating sounds nice.

Comment: (I wasn't aware of the actual nature of the software XD) (By the way, MAJOR PLAUDITS XD)

Comment: For the second method, you will need to install the "git" package, and then from the terminal, `git clone https://github.com/jreese/spotify-gnome`, and then `cd` into the spotify-gnome directory, and then follow the instructions in the readme.

Comment: Alright!  Thanks so much. (I had `git` installed, just didn't know exactly how to do it =P)

Comment: Success!  I've got it installed, works great!  Thank you so much!